# PHP check variable if exists in array of json

Tags: php, laravel

```
Array :  [{"ID":1},{"ID":2}]

$id=1;
```

I want to check if `$id` exists in the array.

Thank you!

Comment: check `json_decode($string, TRUE);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: json_decode needs string, here i have an array

Comment: iterate the array using for loop and use the value as a param to json_decode

Answer (score 4):

You may try Laravel's [Collection::contains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-contains) method, for example:

```php
$collection = collect(json_decode($jsonString, true));

if ($collection->contains(1) {
    // Exists...
}
```

Also, you may use key/value pair like this:

```php
if ($collection->contains('ID', 1) {
    //...
}
```

Also, if you want to get that item from the collection then you may try `where` like this:

```php
$id = $collection->where('ID', 1)->first(); // ['ID' => 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a json formatted array and you need to decode it using `json_decode` first. After that loop the array to check for the id that you want.

So the code should look like this:

```
$json = '[{"ID":1},{"ID":2}]';
$id = 1;

$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data as $item){
   if($item['id'] == $id) {
      echo 'it exists';
   }
}
```

Comment: json_decode90 expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array using for loop and use the value as a param to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$id = 1;
$arr = array('{"ID":1}', '{"ID":2}');
foreach($arr as $val) {
  if (in_array($id, json_decode($val, TRUE))) {
    echo "id present";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if value is exist it will give key of array

```
$jsondata = '[{"ID":1},{"ID":2}]';
$array = json_decode($jsondata,true);

$key = array_search(1, array_column($array, 'ID'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the string is in the json array, with little computation.

I think it's the more efficient way. Check the result [here](https://eval.in/689133).

```
<?php
$id = 1;
$array = ['{"ID":1}', '{"ID":2}'];
echo in_array(json_encode(["ID" => $id]), $array) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```